# OpenSSL 1.0.0-FIPS Symbol Lookup Error

Tags: c++, openssl, undefined-symbol

I wrote a C++ SSL Socket class that uses the OpenSSL API. The version of OpenSSL I am using is "OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips" if that matters. This class belongs to a shared library that I have written.

I am trying to write a bare bones unit test of my class and I cannot get the SSL_CTX structure to allocate.

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef __TDLS_SSL_SOCKET_HPP__
#define __TDLS_SSL_SOCKET_HPP__

#include <stdexcept>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

class TdlsSSLSocket
{
public:
  TdlsSSLSocket(const SSL_METHOD* method);
protected:
  SSL_CTX* ctx;
};

#endif
```

Here is the implementation of the constructor:

```
#include "TdlsSSLSocket.hpp"

TdlsSSLSocket::TdlsSSLSocket(const SSL_METHOD* method)
{
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
  if(!ctx)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize SSL CTX object");
  }
}
```

Here is how I compile this source code:

```
g++  -fPIC -g -O2 -Wall  -c -o TdlsSSLSocket.o TdlsSSLSocket.cpp
ld -r TdlsTCPSocket.o TdlsTCPClient.o TdlsTCPServer.o ReferenceCounter.o TdlsSSLSocket.o -o socket.o
```

Here is how I create the shared library:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libttshared.so.2 -lssl -o libttshared.so.2.0 logger/log.o conf/conf_objs.o seq/seq.o socket/socket.o
```

Here is my C++ unit test where I attempt to exercise the class.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "TdlsSSLSocket.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  SSL_library_init();
  SSL_load_error_strings();

  TdlsSSLSocket ssl_server(TLSv1_method());

}
```

And I build it like so:

```
g++ -o TestSSLServer TestSSLServer.o ../../libttshared.so -L../.. -lttshared
```

And when I execute the unit test, I get the following error:

```
[tlytle@vraptor3 test]$ TestSSLServer
TestSSLServer: symbol lookup error: TestSSLServer: undefined symbol: _ZN13TdlsSSLSocketC1EPK13ssl_method_st
```

The strange undefined symbol `_ZN13TdlsSSLSocketC1EPK13ssl_method_st` almost looks like C++ name mangling could be the culprit. But, I tried wrapping the class in `extern "C"` but I got the same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Regarding *"I cannot get the SSL_CTX structure to allocate ..."* - Does that means it is NULL? If so, from [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki: *"If you fail to initialize the library, then you will experience unexplained errors like SSL_CTX_new returning NULL, error messages like SSL_CTX_new:library has no ciphers and alert handshake failure with no shared ciphers"*.

Comment: Regarding *`_ZN13TdlsSSLSocketC1EPK13ssl_method_st`*: `$ echo _ZN13TdlsSSLSocketC1EPK13ssl_method_st | c++filt` returns 
`TdlsSSLSocket::TdlsSSLSocket(ssl_method_st const*)`. Use `nm` to see if the symbol is present. Try both `TestSSLServer.o` and `libttshared.so`.

Comment: The error that is being output appears to come from the OpenSSL implementation. For example, it is not a uncaught std::runtime_error exception that is causing the program to abort. I do not even think it gets so far as checking to see if ctx is NULL. I believe the SSL_CTX_new() function is aborting the program and spitting out the undefined symbol error.

Comment: The output of `nm TestSSLServer.o` shows `U _ZN13TdlsSSLSocketC1EPK13ssl_method_st` in the list.

Comment: The output of `nm libttshared.so` shows `000000000000b000 T _ZN13TdlsSSLSocketC1EPK13ssl_method_st` and `000000000000b000 T _ZN13TdlsSSLSocketC2EPK13ssl_method_st`

Comment: You should probably use `c++filt` so you get friendly names. The `U` means undefined, so another object file has to provide the symbol. The `T` means the symbol present in the text section, and its public. A lower `t` means the symbol is present in the text section, but its privaye. Also see the [`nm` man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm).

Comment: Found it! I am not linking to the library that I think I am. In the man page for `nm`, it states that a "U" type means it is an undefined symbol. I did a `ldd` on TestSSLServer and it shows that the `libttshared.so` is pointing to a different directory than the one I am building. I need to set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (just for testing purposes) to use my new library rather than the old one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who reads this, the problem was not the OpenSSL library. The undefined symbol problem means that the linker could not resolve the given symbol. I performed a `ldd` on the unit test binary TestSSLServer and it revealed that I was not linking to the current version of `libttshared.so`. I set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to include the directory of the new shared library and the program executed successfully.